# How to design a binary counter with 4029 binary counter ic

Tags: integrated-circuit, counter, 555

I am trying to build a circuit that counts up to 15 or 1111 in binary using a 4029 ic and 4 LEDs as demonstrated in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1l2AHLuEKw). I have studied the 4029 datasheet, and I still can't figure out how to wire this up on a breadboard. There seems to be very little information on how to use this ic. My current problem is that I do not understand what I would need to do with the carry in and carry out pins of the 4029 to make the counter work as stated above. When I tried to hookup the circuit according to the datasheet my circuit didn't work as demonstrated in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4GjtQTQMig&feature=youtu.be).  I redid the entire circuit from scratch, and i am still facing the same problems, so i don't think it is a simple error that I made.  Finally I was unsure if I was supposed to simply connect UP/DN and BIN/DEC to VDD to make them logically high.

Here are the steps I took in setting up the circuit:

1. I built an astable multivibrator using 555 timer
2. I connected pin 3 of 555 to pin 15 of 4029
3. I connected vss and vcc to power pins
4. I connected UP/DN and BIN/DEC to V+
5. I connected LEDs from Q1 - Q4 to V-
6. I connected battery to power supply pins

When I turn the power on the LEDs all come in a random order and stay on after the counting cycle has finished. Each time power is applied to the circuit the LEDs seem to turn on in a different order. I was unsure what to do with the carry in and carry out pins so I left them unconnected which may be part of my problem. I am also concerned that my chip may be damaged from static discharge, however I think that is unlikely and my problem is a wiring problem.

Here is my extremely bad sketch of my circuit:

[image]

And finally here is a picture of my circuit:

[image]

Comment: CD4029B datasheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4029b.pdf provides good documentation. What you have tried, what problems you are getting?

Comment: `I connected pin 3 of 555 to pin 7 of 4029` pin 7 is the curry out, how can you connect two outputs together! I think the cause of the problem is that you are "reading" the orientation of the chip placed on the breadboard wrong, in the first video link you have attached pins 1-8 of 4029 are in the purple capacitor side. Pin 3 of 555 goes to pin 15 of 4029.

Comment: I actually do have pin 3 connected to 1 that was just a typo, so that is not the problem

Comment: connect `carry in` and `preset enable (PE)` to GND, leave `carry out` disconnected

Comment: thank you that worked but why is that necessary?

Comment: @popgalop Super late but it's because inputs to CMOS (4000-series chips) should never be left floating because of the dynamic nature of the transistors (see [this answer about floating inputs in general](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/308343/195122))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had to PE and CARRY IN, to give them a logical low or zero.  In reading the datasheet I had missed the part about them needing to be at 0 for the circuit to count normally.

Comment: It is correct in English to capitalize "I" when referring to yourself. I have edited your answer accordingly.